# Unidentified Identifier

Tags: pine-script

I am adding an alert condition and encountered a problem "Unidentified Identifier"

Below are the codes. Can anyone please help me? All I need is to plot the OHLC of Monday value to the rest of the week and alert when price is above Monday High and below of Monday Low?

Thanks.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Monday_HL", shorttitle="Monday_HL", overlay=true)
//holds the daily price levels
openPrice = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)
highPrice = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
lowPrice  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)
closePrice  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close
 
price = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1', close)
 
//function which is called by plot to establish day of the week is monday return true or false
isMonday() => dayofweek(time('D')) == monday ? 1 : 0
 
 
//plot works by combining the isMonday function combined with the price to plot the line for that given condition
plot(isMonday() and lowPrice  ? lowPrice :  na, title="Monday Low",   style=circles, linewidth=2, color=black)
plot(isMonday() and openPrice ? openPrice:  na, title="Monday Open",   style=circles, linewidth=2, color=black)
plot(isMonday() and highPrice ? highPrice:  na, title="Monday High", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=green)
plot(isMonday() and closePrice  ? closePrice :  na, title="Monday close",  style=circles, linewidth=2, color=red)
 
Above = price >  isMonday and highprice ? true : false
 
Below = price > isMOnday and lowprice ? true : false
 
alertcondition(Above, title='Price above Monday High', message='Price is above Monday high!')
alertcondition(Below, title='Price Below Monday Low', message='Price is below Monday low!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error in your code comes from :

```
isMonday() => dayofweek(time('D')) == monday ? 1 : 0
```

And, in your code, monday is not defined.

In pinescript dayofweek() returns a integer. In pinescript v5? you can use dayofweek.monday for comparaison, so you should use :

```
isMonday() => dayofweek(time('D')) == dayofweek.monday ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has `//@version=5` declaration but not everything is written in `v5`.

Below are the changes you need to make:

- The built-in variable `monday` is now `dayofweek.monday`
- Plot styles also have a namespace so `circles` should be
  `plot.style_circles`
- Any color should have `color.` namespace. `black` should be
  `color.black`